# How to parse time to String value in android?

Tags: android, time

I have time value from server returned as 13:00:45:888 which is returned as TIME value from SAP backend . How can I convert it to 01:00 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can try the code below.

SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss:SSS");
            Date serverTime = sdf2.parse(ValueFromServer);
            ResultYouWant = sdf1.format(serverTime);
```

Comment: I am getting TIME value from server

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help

```
String str = "08:03:10 pm";
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
 Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);
```

or

```
try {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a"); //if 24 hour format
    // or
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); // 12 hour format

    java.util.Date d1 =(java.util.Date)format.parse(your_Time);

    java.sql.Time ppstime = new java.sql.Time(d1.getTime());

} catch(Exception e) {

    Log.e("Exception is ", e.toString());
}
```